# Restricting vimeo video to domain-level privacy not working

Tags: django, video, vimeo

I have a django websites where I want to embed my own vimeo videos and I want the video to play in my website only. For that I restricted the video to domain-level privacy. But still it's showing error in my website

> Because of its privacy settings, this video cannot be played here.

How can I play the video?

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="{{ video_link }}" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In this way I am embedding video.

Even when I am doing curl request by passing the referral (my website domain), it returns 200.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the default referrer policy value helped me to solve the same issue.
Check this man page for more details: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_referrerpolicy.asp

In my case it works well with `referrerpolicy="strict-origin"`. So you can try to change your iframe as follows:

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" referrerpolicy="strict-origin" src="{{ video_link }}" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```